# Find camera translation given 3d world coordinates and 2d image points

Tags: camera-calibration

I only know my camera rotation `R`, but without the translational component `T`. Intrinsics are known, and I have a set of 3D points `P` with their 2D correspondences `Q`. Is there a method to compute `T` directly, and at best is differentiable in `P`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an approximate solution in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.09813v5.pdf